# PHP scandir strange behaviour

Tags: php, scandir

ok, so what i'm trying to do is to scan the "previous" folder.

```
$scanned = scandir("..");
foreach($scanned as $file){

if(is_file($file)){
    print $file."<br />";       
   }
}
```

even though in my ".." directory i have 20+ files i get just three rows

```
index.jpg
index.php
template.dtd
```

i noticed that if i don;t use that is_file if clause it returns all file names; but i really need that if clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a while guess that those three files exist in both the current directory and the parent directory. `scandir()` only returns filenames, and you're calling `is_file($file)` when you mean `is_file("../$file")`.

Comment: no, that was something else(i tried everything :D )...i removed that piece from my code

Comment: so my code was strange overall :))(it's 5AM in my country :P) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your function is testing for those filenames in the current directory and not in the previous directory.  To get the desired result, try: is_file('../' . $file) instead.